# Form validation with multiple highlighted fields

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a registration form that I would like to have multiple field validation. What I mean by this is if more than one field is not filled in it will be highlighted red. I have some code already written but instead of highlighting the field not filled in, it's highlighting all of them. I realise it is quite long winded but I'm fairly new to this. My JS code is as follows:

```
`function formCheck() {
    var val = document.getElementById("fillMeIn").value;
    var val = document.getElementById("fillMeIn2").value;
    var val = document.getElementById("fillMeIn3").value;
    var val = document.getElementById("fillMeIn4").value;
    var val = document.getElementById("fillMeIn5").value;
    var val = document.getElementById("fillMeIn6").value;
    var val = document.getElementById("fillMeIn7").value;
    if (val == "") {
        alert("Please fill in the missing fields");
        document.getElementById("fillMeIn").style.borderColor = "red";
        document.getElementById("fillMeIn2").style.borderColor = "red";
        document.getElementById("fillMeIn3").style.borderColor = "red";
        document.getElementById("fillMeIn4").style.borderColor = "red";
        document.getElementById("fillMeIn5").style.borderColor = "red";
        document.getElementById("fillMeIn6").style.borderColor = "red";
        document.getElementById("fillMeIn7").style.borderColor = "red";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("fillMeIn").style.borderColor = "green";
        document.getElementById("fillMeIn2").style.borderColor = "green";
        document.getElementById("fillMeIn3").style.borderColor = "green";
        document.getElementById("fillMeIn4").style.borderColor = "green";
        document.getElementById("fillMeIn5").style.borderColor = "green";
        document.getElementById("fillMeIn6").style.borderColor = "green";
        document.getElementById("fillMeIn7").style.borderColor = "green";
    }
}`
```

My HTML is as follows:

```
'<form id="mbrForm" onsubmit="return formCheck();" action="thanks.html" method="post">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 vertical-gap">
                                    FIRST NAME:
                                    <input id="fillMeIn" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" >
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 vertical-gap">
                                    LAST NAME:
                                    <input id="fillMeIn2" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" >
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                            </div> 

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-8 vertical-gap">
                                    ADDRESS:
                                    <input id="fillMeIn3" type="text" class="form-control vertical-gap" placeholder="First Line" >
                                    <input id="fillMeIn4" type="text" class="form-control vertical-gap" placeholder="Second Line" >
                                    <input id="fillMeIn5" type="text" class="form-control vertical-gap" placeholder="Town/City" >
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 vertical-gap">
                                    POST CODE:
                                    <input id="fillMeIn6" type="text" class="form-control vertical-gap" placeholder="Postcode" >
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 vertical-gap">
                                    PHONE No:
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control vertical-gap" placeholder="Tel no">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    EMAIL ADDRESS:
                                    <input id="fillMeIn7" type="email" class="form-control vertical-gap" placeholder="Email address" >
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row vertical-gap">
                                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    DISCIPLINE:
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">
                                            <input class="form-check-input horizontal-gap" type="checkbox" value="Cross Country"> CROSS COUNTRY
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">
                                            <input class="form-check-input horizontal-gap" type="checkbox" value="Enduro"> ENDURO
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">
                                            <input class="form-check-input horizontal-gap" type="checkbox" value="Downhill"> DOWNHILL
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <!--<button type="button" input type="hidden" class="btn btn-success" name="redirect" value="thanks.html">SUBMIT</button>-->
                                    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                            </div>
                        </form>'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to pass it as resolved if it is.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the ids in an Array, iterate through its values, and execute the repeatable code in a function that groups all the logic inside.

example :

```
["fillMeIn1", "fillMeIn2", "fillMeIn3", "fillMeIn4"].each(function(id){
    // do things with id
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the html "required" property instead?

If you want to do this with JS, you should give each variable a different name. In the code you posted you are continuously overwriting the same variable, and then, it evaluates val (which ended up being assigned to the (fill me7 value) to "", and if true, setting all the borders to red.

Set different variables, push the input values into an array when submit is triggered and loop through them if variables[i]==0, set getElementId(switch case[i] or another array with the name of the inputs[i]).bordercolor to red.

AGAIN, this sound VERY INEFFICIENT and I am not sure at all it would work. My guess is that it would take A LOT of time, and probably get timed out (except you are using some asych/try-catch kind of JS).

I would simply go for an HTML required property and then override the "required" property in CSS to make it look as you intend to. Simpler, easy and clean.

Comment: Hi PitBoss. Yes this is an option to use the HTML required property but I wanted to write something in JS to prove that I could do it. Thanks for your input though!

Comment: Thank you for patience. Let me know if you achieved a viable JS option. If not, hit me up and lets see what we can do

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in your code is that you override the variable `val` each time you wrote `var val = ...`.

Keeping your own your logic, you could write something like that.

```
var formModule = (function () {
    var $fields = [
        document.getElementById('fillMeIn'),
        document.getElementById('fillMeIn2'),
        document.getElementById('fillMeIn3'),
        document.getElementById('fillMeIn4'),
        document.getElementById('fillMeIn5'),
        document.getElementById('fillMeIn6'),
        document.getElementById('fillMeIn7')
    ];

    function markInvalid($field) {
        $field.style.borderColor = 'red';
    }

    function markValid($field) {
        $field.style.borderColor = 'green';
    }

    return {
        check: function () {
            var isValid = true;
            $fields.forEach(function ($f) {
                if ($f.value === '') {
                    if (isValid) alert('Please fill in the missing fields');
                    isValid = false;
                    markInvalid($f);
                }
                else markValid($f);
            });
            return isValid;
        }
    };
})();
```

There are some extra concepts in this example which may be useful:

- Working with the DOM is really slow, that's why you should
  put your elements in a variable once for all and not everytime you
  click on the submit button.
- In my example i wrap the code with `var formModule = (function () {...})();`.
  It's called [module pattern](https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/). The goal is to prevent variables to leak in the rest of the application.

---

A better solution could be this one using the 'power' of html form validation:

**HTML:**

```
 <form id="mbrForm" action="thanks.html" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 vertical-gap">
            FIRST NAME:
            <input id="fillMeIn" type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 vertical-gap">
            LAST NAME:
            <input id="fillMeIn2" type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 vertical-gap">
            ADDRESS:
            <input id="fillMeIn3" type="text" required class="form-control vertical-gap" placeholder="First Line">
            <input id="fillMeIn4" type="text" required class="form-control vertical-gap" placeholder="Second Line">
            <input id="fillMeIn5" type="text" required class="form-control vertical-gap" placeholder="Town/City">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 vertical-gap">
            POST CODE:
            <input id="fillMeIn6" type="text" required class="form-control vertical-gap" placeholder="Postcode">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 vertical-gap">
            PHONE No:
            <input type="number" class="form-control vertical-gap" placeholder="Tel no">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            EMAIL ADDRESS:
            <input id="fillMeIn7" type="email" required class="form-control vertical-gap" placeholder="Email address">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row vertical-gap">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            DISCIPLINE:
            <div class="form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input horizontal-gap" type="checkbox" value="Cross Country"> CROSS COUNTRY
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input horizontal-gap" type="checkbox" value="Enduro"> ENDURO
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input horizontal-gap" type="checkbox" value="Downhill"> DOWNHILL
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
var formModule = (function () {
    var $form = document.getElementById('mbrForm');
    var $btn = document.getElementById('btnSubmit');
    var $fields = [
        document.getElementById('fillMeIn'),
        document.getElementById('fillMeIn2'),
        document.getElementById('fillMeIn3'),
        document.getElementById('fillMeIn4'),
        document.getElementById('fillMeIn5'),
        document.getElementById('fillMeIn6'),
        document.getElementById('fillMeIn7')
    ];

    checkValidation();

    $form.addEventListener('change', checkValidation);
    $form.addEventListener('keyup', checkValidation);
    $fields.forEach(function ($f) {
        $f.addEventListener('change', function () {
            markInput($f, $f.checkValidity());
        });
    });

    function checkValidation() {
        $btn.disabled = !$form.checkValidity();
    }

    function markInput($field, isValid) {
        $field.style.borderColor = isValid ? 'green' : 'red';
    }
})();
```

In this example, the button gets disabled until the form is valid and inputs are validated whenever they are changed.

I added `required` attribute in HTML inputs so they can be handled by native javascript function `checkValidity()`. Note that in this case inputs email and number are also correctly checked. You could also use attribute `pattern` to get a more powerfull validation:

```
<input type="text" pattern="-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?">
```

Hope it helps.